# VS: Separating headers from source files?

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

I know this is completely subjective, but I'm curious: do you use separate filters for headers and source files in your Visual Studio solutions? Visual Studio creates "Header Files" and "Source Files" filters by default. To me, this dichotomy causes more annoyance than anything else.

What's your take on this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes! I find it particularly useful for C++ projects/solutions.